# hudson: Variable that returns which user initiated the build?

Tags: java, hudson

is it possible to get the username of the user who initiated a build on Hudson ? There doesn't seem to be any hudson environment variable for username.

otherwise, how are you supposed to return specific builds running under a certain user remotely using the API ?

Comment: Do you want the user that's running the Hudson master process or the salve where your build is running, or do you need the user who checked in the code that triggered the build ?

Comment: the user who saved the build and clicked run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you state why you need the jobs started by a specific user? If it is just for the particular user than it might be enough to just use the security settings, which will limit the amount of jobs that they are seeing. In addition, for my installation, it will usually not show anything, because the vast majority of the jobs will only be triggered by the SCM. Following some ideas.

You can try the remote API.

```
http://<HudsonURL>/job/<JobName>/lastBuild/api/xml
```

The previous link will return an XML file. There you should find a cause tag. I don't know if that information is available when the job is still running.

Alternatively, ask for an extension of the [Job Filter Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/View+Job+Filters) to incorporate a filter for jobs last run (or that are currently running) by username.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for a long time. To answer your question - 
 yes, you can read who started the job while it is still running.

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Quick+and+Simple+Security shows a way to launch hudson as a specific user.

`$ java -jar hudson.war --argumentsRealm.passwd.user=password --argumentsRealm.roles.user=admin`

It seems argumentsRealm will hopefully have some user information in it.